# FaceBook notifications not works

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to ask, I have this code:

```
         echo '
 <form action="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$data['user_id'].'/notifications?access_token='.$data['oauth_token'].'&href=some_url&template=hello" method="POST">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

If i want to send it, this message appears:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 15
>      }
>   }

But if I want to post to my wall, or create new photo album, it works properly with this token.

Thanks for any help, I do not know what else to do.

Comment: What’s unclear about the message? There are [different types of tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for different purposes. And interacting with the API via a simple HTML form might be OK for testing puropses (although that’s easier with the Graph API Explorer), but if you want to use it more seriously, you should make use of the PHP SDK for stuff like that.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for answer, it is impossible to test post notifications via graph api explorer. What do you think, which token may be this? It is not the same token as token to post to wall?

Comment: No, it’s not impossible to test notifications with the Graph API Explorer. (I have done it myself already – successfully. In fact, it’s what I do with almost everything concerning the API. Why should I start to write scripts first, when I can figure out how stuff works there quite simple and without any need for actual coding?) As for the token question – please _read_ the documentation page I linked to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct `access_token` as you can tell from the error. Your app access_token can be created using your App ID and App Secret:

`$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;`

[This tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/09/28/facebook-api-app-notifications-api-for-facebook-canvas-apps/) will be able to help you more.